# Look at specific point in LWJGL

Tags: java, lwjgl

Trying to make some code to look at a specific point in the world. ChatGPT isn't helping. Probably should have paid attention in school. Here's what I have so far (it doesn't work very well but Y is on to something)

```java
public void lookAtCoordinate(Vector3f target) {
    double xSide = target.x - position.x;
    double ySide = target.y - position.y;
    double zSide = target.z - position.z;
    setRotation((float) Math.toDegrees(Math.acos(xSide / ySide)), (float) -Math.toDegrees(Math.acos(xSide / zSide)), 0);
    //setRotation(target.x - position.x, target.y - position.x, 0;
}
```

Help?

Game controls:

```java
Game.newKeybind(GLFW_KEY_S, () -> { Game.cameraInc.z = 1; });
Game.newKeybind(GLFW_KEY_W, () -> { Game.cameraInc.z = -1; });
Game.newKeybind(GLFW_KEY_D, () -> { Game.cameraInc.x = 1; });
Game.newKeybind(GLFW_KEY_A, () -> { Game.cameraInc.x = -1; });
Game.newKeybind(GLFW_KEY_SPACE, () -> { Game.cameraInc.y = 1; });
Game.newKeybind(GLFW_KEY_LEFT_SHIFT, () -> { Game.cameraInc.y = -1; });
```

Comment: Are you using the z-axis? Is this 2D or 3D?

Comment: Yes, making a 3D game. Camera y is side to side, x is up and down. 90 y would be looking right.

Comment: So it's a right-handed coordinate system (because of OpenGL) with Z facing up.

Comment: Think so? Kinda new to this sort of thing. My controls are
        Game.newKeybind(GLFW_KEY_S, () -> {Game.cameraInc.z = 1;});
        Game.newKeybind(GLFW_KEY_W, () -> {Game.cameraInc.z = -1;});
        Game.newKeybind(GLFW_KEY_D, () -> {Game.cameraInc.x = 1;});
        Game.newKeybind(GLFW_KEY_A, () -> {Game.cameraInc.x = -1;});
        Game.newKeybind(GLFW_KEY_SPACE, () -> {Game.cameraInc.y = 1;});
        Game.newKeybind(GLFW_KEY_LEFT_SHIFT, () -> {Game.cameraInc.y = -1;});
if that helps.

Comment: I know it's not Java OpenGL code, but the [following WebGL code](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-3d-camera.html#:~:text=Here%27s%20the%20code%20to%20compute%20a%20%22lookAt%22%20matrix) could be ported. It is a function to calculate a "lookAt matrix". It involves normlizing the cross product of two vectors along multiple axis. All of the vector math is given. You just need to supply the position, target, and the "up" vector.